# Passing data between the Tabs of a TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I have a UITabBarController based application and I want to pass data from one view to another. I am doing this in storyboard and I am just doing some testing, before bringing it into the main application.

I am just trying this with a NSString at the moment.

I am able to pass data to the VC in question when I use a modal transition using this code:

```
NSString *sendingString = @"This string has some content";    
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
NextViewController *nVC = (NextViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"goToNextVC"];

nVC.receivingString = sendingString;
[self presentViewController:nVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now this pushes that VC up and passes it as I want it, but instead of pushing up the VC I want it to be pushed to another Tab Bar.

Now I can flick to the desired TabBar with this code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Where I get stuck is, how do I send data to this ViewController???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either subclass your `TabBarController`, and add a property to it, or create a singleton (e.g. DataManager), to which all your `ViewControllers` will have access. You can pass your data to it.

Comment: How would I do the sub class? I haven't created a class to subclass the TabBarController to yet. So what would this class contain so that the selected index would show the information properly??

Comment: It would only contain an additional property to hold your data. Nothing special.

Comment: Ok, after a quick google, even though it is slightly more complicated, I will go for the singleton option. It will be more useful to me in the future.