# pass data between tab bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitabbar

I need to pass data between Tab Bar using swift.
can anybody show me how to do this?

I found this articles, but I don't understand objective-C.
[Passing data between the Tabs of a TabBarViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130076/passing-data-between-the-tabs-of-a-tabbarviewcontroller)

Comment: what type of data you want to pass, meanwhile you can also set Tabbar delegates in AppDelegate and pass the data along the controllers with didSelectViewController: funciton

Answer (score 0):

I recently finished a project somewhat like this. You can create a global class:

```
class Balance {

    var balance: Int = 0
    var netWorth: Int = 0

    init(balance: Int, netWorth: Int) {
        self.balance = balance
        self.netWorth = netWorth
    }
}
```

Then outside of any other class make an instance of that class.

```
var balanceInstance = Balance(balance: 0, netWorth: 0)
```

And then in any view of your app you can simply call `balanceInstance.balance = 100` or whatever variables you need to pass between views.

Comment: This solution is in Swift actually, what language are you using?